# redirect additional subdomain in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a problem with an redirect.

I have this code in my htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^frutasadomicilio.cl
RewriteRule ^ http://www.frutasadomicilio.cl%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Redirect 301 /index.html http://www.frutasadomicilio.cl/venta-de-verduras
Redirect 301 http://frutasadomicilio.cl http://www.frutasadomicilio.cl/venta-de-verduras
```

This code is working fine. This code redirects all requests without www to www.

But my problem is when I try to access `resources.frutasadomicilio.cl` that is a subdomain, I am redirected to `www.frutasadomicilio.cl/venta-de-verduras`.

Answer (score -1):

I assume your subdomain points to a subdirectory off the document root of the main domain (a common setup)? eg. `resources.` -> `/resources/...`?

The problem in this case is that the .htaccess file from the parent directory on the *filesystem* is inherited. So, a request for `resources.example.com` will result in a redirect (`Redirect 301 /index.html ...`).

Also, you should not mix mod_alias redirects (ie. `Redirect`) with mod_rewrite redirects (ie. `RewriteRule`). If you are using mod_rewrite then only use mod_rewrite.

> `Redirect 301 http://frutasadomicilio.cl http://www.frutasadomicilio.cl/venta-de-verduras`

This line actually does nothing and should be removed. `Redirect` takes a root-relative path (starting with a slash) as the source path, not an absolute path, so this will never match.

The last two `Redirect`s can be rewritten as the following (using mod_rewrite) to avoid your unwanted redirection:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(index\.html)?$ /venta-de-verduras [R=301,L]
```

Now, the redirection only occurs when the host starts `www.` (so excludes `resources.`).

Alternatively, you can omit the above `RewriteCond` directive and include an .htaccess file in the `/resources` subdirectory with the following directive.

```
RewriteEngine On
```

mod_rewrite directives are not inherited by default, so by simply enabling the rewrite engine in the subdirectory prevents the mod_rewrite directives in the parent .htaccess from being executed (note that other modules in the parent .htaccess file are still processed). This might be preferable if you have a lot of redirects in the parent .htaccess file that need to be excluded.